# How does a chiyuv due to chinuch work?

Tags: halacha-theory, minor-katan-child, chinuch-education, derabanan, lomdus

We frequently see statements in *halacha* like "the minor's obligation to do the *mitzva* is only rabbinically imposed (*mid'rabanan*), because it's only because of *chinuch* (=the obligation to educate one's kids)". This is attributed on this site [to *Mishna B'rura*](/q/28238) and [to *Minchas Chinuch*](/q/27941), though I'm sure it predates them.

This is even sometimes used to allow, e.g., a minor who ate his fill of bread (and would thus be divinely-imposed-obligation obligated in *bircas hamazon* were he an adult) to say *bircas hamazon* for an adult who did not eat his fill (and is thus obligated *mid'rabanan*). Thus we see (seemingly) that the minor's obligation is considered to be in the *mitzva* at hand and not in some third-party *mitzva* like *chinuch* or something (even if it's imposed *because* of *chinuch*).

Am I right in my understanding that there's an obligation on the minor?

If so, how can the rabbis possibly impose an obligation on a minor? He's not considered to have intelligence! How can someone without intelligence be obligated in anything?

And if not, how can the minor exempt an adult in any *mitzva*?

Comment: This needs sources to back up some of its claims. I'm closing it for now and hope to improve it (and anyone else is welcome, even asked, to, also) and reopen it.

Comment: Evidence that a MiDerbannan is a Mitzva Cheftza (it falls on the object - the minor - not the one obligated - the father) perhaps, but beyond that I'm not seeing the question. הם אמרו והם אמרו

Comment: It is a big discussion amongst the rishonim with Rashi and tosafos constantly clashing over the issue. If this reopened I can send some sources